# Correct syntax to use for an If condition in trigger in MariaDB server version

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertCompanyUser AFTER INSERT ON userinfo
 FOR EACH ROW 
   BEGIN
     IF New.companyId is not null THEN
       INSERT INTO `tb_companyuser` (`id`, `companyId`, `userId`, `freeze`, `role`, `createDate`, `updateDate`) VALUES (NULL, New.companyId, New.id, b'00000', '1', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
   END IF
   END
```

error==>
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF
   END' at line 6

when I tried in this way
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same problem you had, I tried everything and it finally worked when I put ";" after my WHERE statement

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `updater` AFTER UPDATE ON `tbl_transport`
FOR EACH ROW
IF (NEW.`customer_id` = '0') 
THEN UPDATE tbl_user SET tbl_user.`user_requested_car` = false
WHERE tbl_user.`user_email` = NEW.`customer_id`;
END IF;
```

Comment: ok, funny thing, I tried the very same thing again and it failed with a "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5". Can somebody please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should add an ";" after the "END IF".

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER insertCompanyUser AFTER INSERT ON userinfo
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF New.companyId is not null THEN
        INSERT INTO `tb_companyuser` (`id`, `companyId`, `userId`, `freeze`, `role`, `createDate`, `updateDate`) VALUES (NULL, New.companyId, New.id, b'00000', '1', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
    END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```